# Python: How to sum a column in a CSV file while skipping the header row

Tags: python-3.x, csv

Trying to sum a column in a csv file that has a header row at the top.  I'm trying to use this for loop but it's just return zero.  Any thoughts?

```
CSVFile = open('Data103.csv')
CSVReader = csv.reader(CSVFile) #you don't pass a file name directly to csv.reader
CSVDataList = list(CSVReader) #stores the csv file as a list of lists

print(CSVDataList[0][16])

total = 0
for row in CSVReader:
   if CSVReader.line_num == 1:
        continue 
        total += int(row[16])
print (total)
```

Here is what the data sample looks like in txt: 
Value,Value,Value, "15,500.05", 00.00, 00.00
So the items are deliminted by , except in the case where they need an escape then it's "".  It's a pretty standard file with a header row and about 1k lines of data across 18 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv')
column_sum = df['column_name'].sum()
```

Comment: Haven't played around with pandas yet.  Does it automatically skip the header because I don't see in your code how it would take that row out?  Thank you.

Comment: by default it uses the first line as header, so it could automatically get column names.

Comment: Cool thanks but I tried this and it spits out a huge list of nonsensical numbers.  I tried to run a for loop over it but the numbers will have both , and . as separators.

Comment: do you mean the `,` as thousand separator? what's your column separator in your csv?

Comment: the , is the separator, however they are using " to escape the thousands separators. What the data is now doing is if it looks like this in CSV: 00.00,00.00 it is translating it as 00.0000.00 so it's basically just smushing all the numbers together.

Comment: I can't see your data. Could you update your question to show what your data is like?

Comment: I did.  Please see above.  Thanks

Comment: I think I see the problem that pandas is experiencing.  It cannot sum because the values in the column are strings.  I have played around with several variations but cannot seem to get it to convert to integers.  If I take off the .sum() I get a list with a value assigned to it.  I cannot iterate over those values because the escape character is " and causes and issue.  I tried doublequotes=' " '  but it gives me a syntax error.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you've over-indented the line that does the sum. It should be like this:

```py
for row in CSVReader:
    if CSVReader.line_num == 1:
        continue 
    total += int(row[16])
```

Otherwise you'll only sum the values for the first row, which is exactly the one you want to skip.

**EDIT:**
Since you said the previous change doesn't work, I'd suggest working with the excellent Python lib called [rows](https://github.com/turicas/rows).

With the following CSV (`fruits.csv`):

```
id,name,amount
1,apple,3
2,banana,6
3,pineapple,2
4,lemon,5
```

You can access columns directly by their name instead of their index:

```py
import rows
data = rows.import_from_csv('fruits.csv')
for fruit_data in data: 
    print(fruit_data.name, fruit_data.amount)
    # output:
    # apple 3
    # banana 6
    # pineapple 2
    # lemon 5
```

**NEW EDIT:**
After you've provided the data, I believe in your case you could do something like:

```py
import rows
data = rows.import_from_csv('Data103.csv')
print(data.field_names[16])  # prints the field name

total = 0
for row in data: 
    value = row.<column_name> 
    value = value.replace(',', '')  # remove commas
    total += float(value)
print (total)
```

Comment: Yeah I was playing around with it.  Unfortunately that does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Thunder185 See my updated answer with a much simpler lib/approach :)

Comment: @Thunder185 Please remember to mark one of the answers as the correct one if it solved your problem :) If not, please let us know what's missing.

Comment: So far nothing is working.  I even tried pandas super easy solution:  'code' df = pandas.read_csv('Data103.csv', index_col='ReferenceAccountID', parse_dates=['AsOfDate']) then total = df['column header name'].sum() and this results in the same continuous string of all values in that column.

Comment: @Thunder185 Can you please add a sample of your data so we can better understand it?

Comment: Yeah it's up top.  Thank you.  Also, the pandas sum function is just smooshing the output together so I'm thinking it needs to be told what the delimiters are.  For example, as above, the data is separated by columns until there is a comma in a number, then it is escaped by quotes.  So for example, 00.00,00.00,"50,342.01",00.00,"11,213.21","541,324.23", etc.  The output looks like this then: 00.0000.0050,342.0100.0011,213.21541,324.23

Comment: @Thunder185 I've edited my answer again, I believe now it fits your needs.

Comment: @Thunder185 Please mark one of the answers as the correct one if it has solved your problem.

Comment: Hey sorry, I am still working through this.  Not familiar with rows but this does not appear to be correct syntax?  .<column_name>

Comment: @Thunder185 That's a placeholder for you to replace with the name of the column you want to access (i.e. `row.Value_15`). The name of the column is printed in the 3rd line of the code, where it has `print(CSVDataList[0][16])`.

Comment: ok, got that sorted but now I get this::      value = value.replace(',', '')  # remove commas
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: @Thunder185 That means `row.<column_name>` is not returning any value for some (or multiple) row(s). Check if `value` contains any value before applying the `.replace()` and the sum.

Comment: Sorry, jammed up today at work.  Will try to check later or tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Thank you for all your help here.  I eventually solved it by removing the double quotes and then unnecessary commas.  I had the provider of the file do it and just used data frames in pandas with a simple .sum() for the column I needed.  Really appreciate all your efforts here though.

Comment: @Thunder185 Cool, glad that you figured it out! If one of the answers here solved your problem or pointed you in the right direction, don't forget to mark it as the correct answer so people can refer to it in the future. Best of luck!